# What is 'dev' folder when using zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh

I'm currently using macOSX
and I just installed oh-my-zsh for using customized UI like 'robbyrussell'

After using zsh, I ran across some folder called 'dev' 
- full absolute path is /dev

it wasn't exist in '/' until I've used in just normal terminal ( not zsh )

What is 'dev' folder for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev` is short for devices. On Unix systems (MacOS is a derivate of UNIX via NextStep and BSD) `/dev` contains file representations of peripheral devices (disks, keyboards, terminals, etc.) and pseudo-devices (random number generators (`/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom`), Null-file (`/dev/null`), etc.).

Have a look at the `hier` manpage (`man 7 hier`) for some information on the filesystem hierarchy.

I am not sure why `/dev` would not have shown up before. It is usually hidden in *Finder* but should be visible in the terminal, no matter which shell.

Comment: I think you're right
Although I've never noticed it, There have been a folder called 'dev'
And thanks for answer. It helps me to understand about 'dev' folder

Comment: I never knew about the `hier` man page, so +1 for mentioning it.